# Scraping website: how to load more results and getting hidden url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i'm trying to scrape this site:
[https://www.flashscore.com/basketball/italy/serie-a2-2021-2022/results/"](https://www.flashscore.com/basketball/italy/serie-a2-2021-2022/results/%22)

The first issue is that when the page is loaded at the end there's a link "Show more matches" but if i inspect document there's only this

class="event__more event__more--static" href="#">Show more matches

but no link...so i don't know how to get the link to make python click on it.

The second issue is always about hidden url: if you click on every match a pop-up open (the first match for example get this: https://www.flashscore.com/match/z1DMLBiE/#/match-summary/match-summary). Also these links are hidden when i inspect, i would be interesed to gettin these or simply getting the code after the /match/ part, in the example above z1DMLBiE.
Every match correspond to a different code, there's also an ID when you inspect that contain thes code but i'm not able to isolate it, only got a whole list from which i cannot exctrat it.

My little piece of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

URL = "https://www.flashscore.com/basketball/italy/serie-a2-2021-2022/results/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")


for div in soup.find_all(class_='sportName basketball'):
    
  
    print(div)


driver.quit()
```

Thanks for any kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extracting the links to follow programmatically, you can click the actual UI element with a simulated cursor using Selenium: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/interactions/#click

Comment: Tried this: driver.find_element_by_class_name('event__more event__more--static').click()  but got error 
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".event__more event__more--static"} Same with find_element_by_css_selector

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally! For sure there are cleaner way of looping but for me it's a good step!
Here's the new code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

URL = "https://www.flashscore.com/basketball/italy/serie-a2-2021-2022/results/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for page to fully render
sleep(5)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()

javaScript = "document.getElementsByClassName('event__more event__more--static')[0].click();"

flag = True

while flag:
    try:
        sleep(3)
        javaScript
        if (javaScript != 0):
            driver.execute_script(javaScript)
            sleep(3)
    except:        
        flag = False
      
try:
    list = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'g_3_')]")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("cannot find match id")
    
for i in list:
    print(i.get_attribute('id').replace("g_3_", ""))
        
driver.close()
```